# GKE NEG Ingress always returns 502 Bad Gateway

Tags: kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine, gke-networking

I have a StatefulSet, Service with NEG, and Ingress set up on Google Cloud Kubernetes Engine cluster.

Every workload and network object is ready and healthy. Ingress is created and NEG status is updated for all the services. VPC-native (Alias-IP) and HTTP Load Balancer options are enabled for the cluster.

But when I try to access my application using a path specified in my Ingress I always get 502 (Bad Gateway) error.

Here is my configuration (names are redacted including image name):

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  annotations:
    cloud.google.com/neg: '{"ingress": true}'
  labels:
    app: myapp
  name: myapp
spec:
  ports:
  - port: 80
    protocol: TCP
    targetPort: tcp
  selector:
    app: myapp
---
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: StatefulSet
metadata:
  labels:
    app: myapp
  name: myapp
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: myapp
  serviceName: myapp
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: myapp
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: myapp
        livenessProbe:
          httpGet:
            path: /
            port: tcp
            scheme: HTTP
          initialDelaySeconds: 60
        image: myapp:8bebbaf
        ports:
        - containerPort: 1880
          name: tcp
          protocol: TCP
        readinessProbe:
          failureThreshold: 1
          httpGet:
            path: /
            port: tcp
            scheme: HTTP
        volumeMounts:
        - mountPath: /data
          name: data
      securityContext:
        fsGroup: 1000
      terminationGracePeriodSeconds: 10
  volumeClaimTemplates:
  - metadata:
      labels:
        app: myapp
      name: data
    spec:
      accessModes:
      - ReadWriteOnce
      resources:
        requests:
          storage: 1Gi
---
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: myapp-ingress
spec:
  rules:
  - http:
      paths:
      - path: /workflow
        backend:
          serviceName: myapp
          servicePort: 80
```

What's wrong with it and how can I fix it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After much digging and tests I finally found what's wrong. Also, it seems like GKE NEG Ingress is not very stable (indeed NEG is in beta) and does not always conform to Kubernetes specs.

There was [an issue with GKE Ingress](https://github.com/kubernetes/ingress-gce/issues/832) related to named ports in `targetPort` field. The fix is implemented and available from **1.16.0-gke.20** cluster version ([Release](https://github.com/kubernetes/ingress-gce/releases/tag/v1.8.0)), which as of today (February 2020) is available under Rapid Channel, but I have not tested the fix as I had other issues with an ingress on a version from this channel.

So basically there are 2 options if you experience the same issue:

1. Specify exact port number and not port name in a `targetPort` field in your service. Here is a fixed service config file from my example:

   ```
   apiVersion: v1
   kind: Service
   metadata:
     annotations:
       cloud.google.com/neg: '{"ingress": true}'
     labels:
       app: myapp
     name: myapp
   spec:
     ports:
     - port: 80
       protocol: TCP
       # !!!
       # targetPort: tcp
       targetPort: 1088
     selector:
       app: myapp
   ```
2. Upgrade GKE cluster to 1.16.0-gke.20+ version (haven't tested it myself).

Comment: Can confirm this is still the case. Using port number in the ingress solved the problem to me.